# How to remove the black line below BottomTabNavigator

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm using createBottomTabNavigator in React Native using react-navigation v4 and can't find a way to remove the black line below the bottom bar that sits in the middle

[image]

Comment: I think that's the home button on newer iphone versions, if i'm not mistaken.
Maybe you can't remove it, or you just need to make your app work on fullscreen. (I think)

Comment: @Wiliam Brochensque junior I think you might be right as I've just tested on another iPhone and the bar is not visible. Cheers

Comment: yeah, that's one of the bad parts of developing apps for IOS. Cheers.

Comment: Would you know how to make the white background behind transparent?